# SQLite Database issue not inserting data in the database

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a created database using the SQLite database in android. my database in create but when clicking on in the insert button it shows me "Data inserted" but not adding data into the database.

DatabaseHelper.java

```
      package abc.example.sqlitetraining;
      import android.content.ContentValues; 
      import android.content.Context;
      import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
      import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

      public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

      public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";

      public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "SURNAME";
    public static final String COL_4 = "MARKS";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER 
       PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SURNANE TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int 
    newVersion) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME );
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String surname, String marks){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, surname);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, marks);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1) {

            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
      }
     }
```

MainActivity.java

```
     package abc.example.sqlitetraining;

     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.Toast;

     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    Button btn_inser_data;
    EditText text_Name, text_Surname, text_Marks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    btn_inser_data = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_insert);

        text_Name   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        text_Surname   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSurname);
        text_Marks   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMarks);

        btn_inser_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean isInserted = 
       myDb.insertData(text_Name.getText().toString(),
                        text_Surname.getText().toString(),
                        text_Marks.getText().toString());

                if (isInserted = true) {
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data inserted", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data is not inserted", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
      }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Name: "/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSurname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Surname: " />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMarks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Marks: "/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTextMarks"
        android:id="@+id/btn_insert"
        android:text="INSERT"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

My app running correctly not showing any error message but not inserting the data into the database. when i trying save data it shows me a blank database. what should I do? please help and thanks.

Comment: Try this : https://www.androidauthority.com/use-sqlite-store-data-app-599743/

Comment: Most of the SQLite mistake is not a proper space or Captial or lower case not porper used in command.

Comment: What tool are u using to check database.

Comment: DB Browser for SQLite.

Comment: Post insert method code

Comment: I have posted all the code you can check.

Comment: did you try uninstall and install the app again ? is table created in database if you have checked the db in sqlite browser ?

Comment: Yes, I checked in the SQLite browser table was created but still, there is no change in my database file.

Answer (score 0):

do not initilize `boolean` inside `if`, it will always return `true` if you initilize there

```
if (isInserted) {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data inserted", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data is not inserted", 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

just use it like this

Comment: Now I am facing "Data is not inserted".

Answer (score 0):

Use `insertOrThrow` method to insert the data.It will throw an exception if your db constraints don't allow a specific insertion. You will get to know the error.